# Sum all columns that match wildcard patterns in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to capture the aggregated number of items in each subcategories and categories. Each category has the same finite set of subcategories.There is a finite set of category as well. I intend to capture the aggregation using this schema:

| Timestamp | Count_CatA_Sub1 | Count_CatA_Sub2 | ... | Count_CatD_Sub6 | Count_CatD_Sub7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-29 | 1 | 2 | ... | 27 | 28 |

But I need to visualize the number of items in a category as well. With the above sample row, I need the output:

| Timestamp | CountA | CountB | CountC | CountD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-29 | 28 | 77 | 126 | 175 |

I would rather not have to type out `CountA=Count_CatA_Sub1 + Count_CatA_Sub2 +... Count_CatA_Sub7`. Is it possible to do these with wildcard in Kusto? Or a better schema?

Comment: Hm, why not capture the aggregation in a schema like `Timestamp`, `Category`, `SubCategory`, `Count`? Comes down on your original dataset and your aggregation query but that probably warrants a different question

Comment: These event instances come from EventHub so we want to have less instances. With the `Timestamp,Cat,Subcat,Count` approach, the event volume will be hundred times more (n cat x m subcat)

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, added sampled data and required results

Comment: Can't you batch your events when sending like sending multiple objects as line-break separated json (many lines in one event, each line a single json object)? ADX imports that without any issue (this is how we feed out data).

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the [`narrow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/narrowplugin) plugin plus some conditional summarizing.

```
datatable(Timestamp: datetime, CatA_Sub1: int, CatA_Sub2: int, CatB_Sub1: int) [
    datetime(2022-11-28 11:50:00), 1, 2, 3,
    datetime(2022-11-28 11:51:00), 4, 5, 6,
    datetime(2022-11-28 11:52:00), 7, 8, 9,
    datetime(2022-11-28 11:53:00), 10, 11, 12,
    datetime(2022-11-28 11:54:00), 13, 14, 15,
    datetime(2022-11-28 11:55:00), 16, 17, 18
]
| evaluate narrow()
| summarize Timestamp = maxif(todatetime(Value), Column == 'Timestamp'),
            TotalCount = sumif(toint(Value), Column != 'Timestamp') by Row
| project-away Row
```

Output:

| Timestamp | TotalCount |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-28 11:50:00.0000000 | 6 |
| 2022-11-28 11:51:00.0000000 | 15 |
| 2022-11-28 11:52:00.0000000 | 24 |
| 2022-11-28 11:53:00.0000000 | 33 |
| 2022-11-28 11:54:00.0000000 | 42 |
| 2022-11-28 11:55:00.0000000 | 51 |

Not sure if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let t = materialize(print Timestamp = range(datetime(2022-11-29), datetime(2022-12-03), 1d),  Cat = range(0, 3), Sub = range(1, 7) | mv-expand Timestamp   to typeof(datetime) | mv-expand Cat         to typeof(int) | mv-expand Sub         to typeof(int) | serialize Val = row_number() | extend Col = strcat("Count_Cat", tostring(make_string(to_utf8("A")[0] + Cat)) ,"_Sub", Sub) | evaluate pivot(Col, take_any(Val), Timestamp));
// Solution starts here
t
| project Timestamp, Metrics = bag_remove_keys(pack_all(), dynamic(["Timestamp"]))
| mv-apply Metrics on 
  (
      extend k = tostring(bag_keys(Metrics)[0])
    | extend v = tolong(Metrics[k])
    | parse k with "Count_Cat" Cat "_Sub" Sub:int
    | summarize sum(v) by Cat
    | summarize make_bag(bag_pack(strcat("Count", Cat), sum_v))
  )
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag_)
```

| Timestamp | CountA | CountB | CountC | CountD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-29T00:00:00Z | 28 | 77 | 126 | 175 |
| 2022-11-30T00:00:00Z | 224 | 273 | 322 | 371 |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 420 | 469 | 518 | 567 |
| 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 616 | 665 | 714 | 763 |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 812 | 861 | 910 | 959 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3VSu47bMBDsDfgfFqpIRI5tpcgLKYKrk%20aCNMZBWNtrW7FICtRKdwru47PLk3V2gqggiH3MDGe0XMI9uqYm2CMjHMlTRK6CfwvfA0ODkSEcgE8Ebai71JnPamJg%20AIOmWKFdfWbTBMrz/CjctSyIEo3oj%20SEVxiqZpiVRSL9XpRfLQ5/FUtFqt3Ul3v5YA75Gl7lYM27rvtVFrn8N7CM7h%20QU8N%20v0VKQAH4KGhcJiIb2cV/PK9zor02zEl/O9Ye3k0/MRadYXH0nduS9Fom56YlClor%20W4QzbZXeg8l8Ke5QIo1cofjcMzleOdQ9nx4YPJvmZ2s3qANyrVWsizUsRkyYOE3mPdydOgqfrARlgEUHHQD0b0iFuTH9Z%20ns%20WEvEYnaiRQFs4UaT5jOezZ2hi%20EW7q%20By%20EaiaNeK%20C0ey0gu9FSeaWhNg7tziXVtNMHBo6t2ZpNNq9mDtYopNmLT1MOEJMzzGYDRQ7/RobNQTF4oVyIZl9QE%207IwWdqnhTrI%20Di1Ob8Oyc/akoA%20VnyCK8NT5i8uqomfJMXLSts5h1GTlJvpLWwHnf63nZISiUmm2mBugpV4NK1cN8reJknJiikt3et82tSr/QPf%20RFbeQMAAA==)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let t = materialize(print Timestamp = range(datetime(2022-11-29), datetime(2022-12-03), 1d),  Cat = range(0, 3), Sub = range(1, 7) | mv-expand Timestamp   to typeof(datetime) | mv-expand Cat         to typeof(int) | mv-expand Sub         to typeof(int) | serialize Val = row_number() | extend Col = strcat("Count_Cat", tostring(make_string(to_utf8("A")[0] + Cat)) ,"_Sub", Sub) | evaluate pivot(Col, take_any(Val), Timestamp));
// Solution starts here
t
| project Timestamp, Metrics = bag_remove_keys(pack_all(), dynamic(["Timestamp"]))
| mv-expand kind=array Metrics 
| extend k = tostring(Metrics[0]), v = tolong(Metrics[1])
| parse k with "Count_Cat" Cat "_Sub" Sub:int
| extend Col = strcat("Count", Cat)
| evaluate pivot(Col, sum(v), Timestamp)
```

| Timestamp | CountA | CountB | CountC | CountD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-29T00:00:00Z | 28 | 77 | 126 | 175 |
| 2022-11-30T00:00:00Z | 224 | 273 | 322 | 371 |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 420 | 469 | 518 | 567 |
| 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 616 | 665 | 714 | 763 |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 812 | 861 | 910 | 959 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3VSTW%20bQBC9W/J/GHHaVXFt6CH9UA5Vzu0lVS6RhcZ4bG9hd9EykBDlx3eWOgRHCQeE5s2%209/Y91mu4RdvUBHtkhCM5CsjGu8/w2zM0GBj8AfhE0Pq6G5HloiYGhmuwyBQM1uaJVBOMY/hjLLUsjIIGdEdSwkssU5Vv8nyVZav8m07hzTRfbb7INNvLC26Qp9ObFCJw2%202mUZbClYZnsP2KHht0%205koAHvgoSF/mIQvdyP5y/O6K9Yv16Lgh2vty6XhDuvoyz8UrrM7CirC9MgUlXzEWg4lskpufOe4EPUkFUKZGndUFisqzt/si44PX1XyM9H3my18ila1hjQpxEwyZjCy91h3cjVoTO9ZiYoQRh50gxI/ktaUh9Y/lou1VHyuTtxIoS2cKNBywcvFMzTB/6VyVlwKv0gcla2Y3%20GxCGR9T0VFQ6saLKsC61rFBgeH1pTqPpmOJlutI%20drjJVx%202sMAYeJNS6cE6pEYsrijMvVhbwfkdrP5tl25JY/siU5%20WD4BLNUx2L/RxWT%20i5VzZTe6UISjQGPS%209E2nZW9RdZ/gNwTKUyKwMAAA==)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let t = materialize(print Timestamp = range(datetime(2022-11-29), datetime(2022-12-03), 1d),  Cat = range(0, 3), Sub = range(1, 7) | mv-expand Timestamp   to typeof(datetime) | mv-expand Cat         to typeof(int) | mv-expand Sub         to typeof(int) | serialize Val = row_number() | extend Col = strcat("Count_Cat", tostring(make_string(to_utf8("A")[0] + Cat)) ,"_Sub", Sub) | evaluate pivot(Col, take_any(Val), Timestamp));
// Solution starts here
t
| evaluate narrow()
| parse Column with "Count_Cat" Cat "_Sub" Sub:int
| summarize Count     = sumif(tolong(Value), Column != "Timestamp")
           ,Timestamp = todatetime(take_anyif(Value, Column == "Timestamp"))   
            by Row, Cat
| summarize take_any(Timestamp), make_bag(bag_pack(Cat, Count)) by Row
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag_, "Count")
| project-away Row
```

| Timestamp | CountA | CountB | CountC | CountD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-29T00:00:00Z | 28 | 77 | 126 | 175 |
| 2022-11-30T00:00:00Z | 224 | 273 | 322 | 371 |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 420 | 469 | 518 | 567 |
| 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 616 | 665 | 714 | 763 |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 812 | 861 | 910 | 959 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let t = materialize(print Timestamp = range(datetime(2022-11-29), datetime(2022-12-03), 1d),  Cat = range(0, 3), Sub = range(1, 7) | mv-expand Timestamp   to typeof(datetime) | mv-expand Cat         to typeof(int) | mv-expand Sub         to typeof(int) | serialize Val = row_number() | extend Col = strcat("Count_Cat", tostring(make_string(to_utf8("A")[0] + Cat)) ,"_Sub", Sub) | evaluate pivot(Col, take_any(Val), Timestamp));
// Solution starts here
let cat = 4;
let sub = 7;
let categories = toscalar
(
    t
    | getschema
    | parse-where ColumnName with "Count_Cat" Cat "_Sub" Sub:int
    | summarize make_set(Cat)
);
t
| project Timestamp, Count = array_split(array_slice(pack_array(*), 1, cat*sub), range(sub, sub*(cat-1), sub))
| mv-expand with_itemindex=i Count
| extend Cat = strcat("Count", tostring(categories[i]))
| evaluate pivot(Cat, take_any(tolong(array_sum(Count))), Timestamp)
```

| Timestamp | CountA | CountB | CountC | CountD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-29T00:00:00Z | 28 | 77 | 126 | 175 |
| 2022-11-30T00:00:00Z | 224 | 273 | 322 | 371 |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 420 | 469 | 518 | 567 |
| 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 616 | 665 | 714 | 763 |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 812 | 861 | 910 | 959 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3VSTW/bMAy9B8h/IHySMnv52IBuC3oYeu%20lwy5FYbAOk2i1JEOm8zH0x4%20SEycpMB9siaQf%20d7jdApPaJuaYIWMsCFHAdl49xkePUODgcGvgbcEra%207lBmPamJguAeLTMFgbf6SaoJxDL%20MpZYFUbIB3YaU4BJLVC1mi0UxnxeL7zqHD9FFMfsi0flKXvCAPPw9yyEmnrrXITTP4U7DO9hdQYcG3eqqKQB74GNDfj00vq2N4OfnUiuj35bFhv8ta8%20k4TfWcS6/L11nXymomKYDU%20zkY67lUCGr7MF3jkvpnuUCKFHjNsriG5WnM/uy4/U3lf3M9PPsBT7FUbWGPCtlmCxpkNB3WHdCDRqz86ykiwBGHHRHJfOIWoMeWi/Ho6lYfLJOphFDW9hSoN7FKmn9ddnf2iTz3XLI0cYHQ60EZeYKawzjkRqPkir95112httqSxbPAVmalop9bBJF6Kx7REuwN7yFKx2SFT25yO2HiHtGaDtrMUSBe4VIeIoY41HkI1XSI/g/VF3tWw4JWSbFEPBYtk1tWJ3OtalkQbF6K1NATeKu5ZHgRCjLpd8sOedRg4mSTDHX6aJ17HfZjEijNEzWuBUd7k3fN9acfU%20S3vh%207flF1Wfz0oN/tBT5ylL2tZffTkw6qxKi1jc%20/wMqUHMixwMAAA==)